# How can I raise a CollectionChanged event on an ObservableCollection, and pass it the changed items?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

I have a class that inherits from `ObservableCollection` and adds a few additional methods such as `AddRange` and `RemoveRange`

My base method call is this:

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    foreach (var i in collection) Items.Add(i);

    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
}
```

My problem with this is that I want to access `e.NewItems` or `e.OldItems` in the `CollectionChanged` event to perform an action on whatever item is in the collection, and the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` action does not pass in these values

```
void Instances_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null) // e.NewItems is always null
    {
        foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
        {
            if (item is EventInstanceModel)
                ((EventInstanceModel)item).ParentEvent = this;
        }
    }
}
```

So I thought I could just use the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add` instead of `Reset`, however that throws a `Range actions are not supported` exception

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    var addedItems = collection.ToList();
    foreach (var i in addedItems) Items.Add(i);

    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, addedItems));
}
```

So my question is, how can I raise a CollectionChanged event, and pass it the new or old item list?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've been looking into it and apparently the `CollectionChanged` method cannot be raised with multiple items.

So I can call

```
OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
    NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, singleItem));
```

but I can't call

```
OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
    NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, listOfItems));
```

For now what I have done is simply raise the Add event for every item added, but I am still rather unhappy at this since it means I raise the `CollectionChanged` event for every item in the `AddRange` method instead of only once.

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    foreach (var i in collection) 
    {
        Items.Add(i);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
            NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, i));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rick I checked into something like that, but it doesn't pass the `e.NewItems` / `e.OldItems` into the `CollectionChanged` event

Comment: Why not just put the event call outside the foreach loop right after it, then it would only be called once.

Comment: This question was about how to raise a `CollectionChanged` event with the parameter of every item that had been added. The answer is that we have to raise the event individually per item, since it does not support being raised with a collection of items.

Answer (score 5):

This works fine for me "stand-alone". Meaning I'm not using an `ObservableCollection` for data binding. So it's not an `ObservableCollection` issue but rather a `ListCollectionView` limitation.

Please read the following article, it's a very interesting read:

[Nathan Nesbit's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/nathannesbit/addrange-and-observablecollection)

Comment: I did see that link, however he also points out at the bottom in the `Not Quite Done` section that his version of `AddRange` doesn't work if more than one item gets added due to the limitations on `ListCollectionView`. You're right that's it's a limitation of `ListCollectionView` and not `ObservableCollection` though

Comment: The link is now broken.

Comment: Link should be good now.

Answer (score 1):

Your post says: *My problem with this is that I want to access e.NewItems or e.OldItems in the CollectionChanged event to perform an action on whatever item is in the collection, **and the NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset action does not pass in these values***.

We're not "stuck" with that behavior, however, because (as many things OOP) if you don't like how something works, you can inherit it to make a custom event that behaves the way you want it to. **Example**: This custom class inherits from `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` and I've changed its behavior so that `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` *does* pass in the changed values. (In this case I made a new list named `RemovedItems` to avoid confusion but one is free to modify existing collections like `NewItems` or `OldItems` as well.) I use it in production code and it works well for me.

```
public class NotifyCollectionResetEventArgs : NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
{
    public NotifyCollectionResetEventArgs(List<object> removedItems) 
        : base(action: NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
    {
        RemovedItems = removedItems.ToList();
    }
    public List<object> RemovedItems { get; }
}
```

The class that inherits ObservableCollection overrides the Clear method:

```
public class ObservableAttributeValueCollection : ObservableCollection<object>
{
    List<object> _removedItems = null;
    public new void Clear()
    {
        _removedItems = Items.ToList<object>(); // 1. Capture the items.
        base.Clear();                           // 2. Clear the items
        _removedItems = null;                   // 3. Clean up
    }
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        {
            base.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionResetEventArgs(_removedItems));
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, consuming this event in a handler uses the 'is' pattern to assign the `ePlus` variable.

```
void handleCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            if (e is NotifyCollectionResetEventArgs ePlus)
            {
                foreach (var item in ePlus.RemovedItems)
                {
                    // Do Something
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```