# Why ObservableCollection does not have a RemoveAll method?

Tags: .net, wpf, observablecollection

Why `ObservableCollection` doesn't has the `RemoveAll` method like a `List`?

I have implemented an **extension** method to provide this functionality to the `ObservableCollection`, but I would like to understand if there is a specific reason for not providing this functionality.

Would it possibly effect **Data Binding** in some way due to **Collection change**? [This](http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection) post does specify a few things that could go wrong while using `ObservableCollections`, but does not address this question.

Comment: Have you looked at the Clear() method? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132405.aspx)

Comment: It has the method Clear(), which removes all elements from the Collection.

Comment: Well, the RemoveAll() method is not intended to Clear the Collection. Even the List has a Clear() method. It is intended to Remove all the items that match a certain criteria.

Comment: And for any Down Votes, please specify the reason.

Comment: This does not make sense as ObservableCollection implements iList.

Comment: @Blam: RemoveAll ain't part of the interface.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It does have a `Clear()` method that removes all items that you can use instead.

If I had to hazard a guess as to why they used `Clear` instead of `RemoveAll`, I think it would be because `RemoveAll` carries the suggestion that you are removing items from the collection, while `Clear` tells you the items are simply being cleared.

This makes a difference in the type of `CollectionChanged` notification that gets raised. `Clear()` raises a `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` event and does not include the removed items in the event, while `Remove` raises a `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Removed` event, and passes the removed item to the event.

[You cannot raise a `CollectionChanged` event with multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7449401/302677), so raising a `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Removed` event with all the items removed would throw an exception. The alternative would be to raise a `CollectionChanged` event for every item that got removed, which can be quite bad for performance. And simply raising a `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` event would cause some confusion when users are expecting a `Removed` event to occur when they are removing items.

So I am guessing they decided to simply use `.Clear()` instead of `.RemoveAll()` because the name is a better description of what is actually happening behind the scenes.

Comment: I think this explains it. Thanks for such a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well ask why it does not implement `Reverse` or any other method. There simply is no reason to implement more than the most common and absolutely necessary methods. Everything beside `Add` and `Remove` is just convenience. (`RemoveAll` is not even part of the common interfaces that lists implement, and they do have a lot of methods already)