# Drop-down not updating when calling RaisePropertyChanged (Prism, BindableBase, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, prism, inotifypropertychanged

I want to **update the data on drop-down** in a view from my view-model. The data is updated in some objects in my model. I understood that the *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface only works on view-model level. But I thought when the view-model subscribe to an event that I can update my view by raising the *RaisePropertyChanged* for the object in the view-model which needs to be updated.

I call the **UpdateConfiguration()** which triggers to fetch the new data. Becacuse the function **PutSetupWorkspaceConfiguration()** is time consuming it returns the the first data and then compute the rest in the background. After its done its rasing the **IsChanged** event which works. So the method **OnListChanged()** gets called but then the gui does not update.

What am I doing wrong since the **event** and the **getter** gets called?

```
/*viewmodel*/
private SetupWorkspaceConfiguration setupWorkspaceConfiguration;

public ObservableCollection<TestingModel> TestingModels
{
   get => setupWorkspaceConfiguration?.TestingModels; //The event calls getter but the gui does not update the data
}

public async Task UpdateConfiguration(int? projectId)
{
   setupWorkspaceConfiguration = await Task.Run(async () => await setupWorkspaceConfigurationStore.PutSetupWorkspaceConfiguration(projectId));            
   setupWorkspaceConfiguration.IsChanged -= OnListChanged;
   setupWorkspaceConfiguration.IsChanged += OnListChanged;
}
private void OnListChanged(object? sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TestingModels));
}
```

**EDIT:**
The elements in the list **setupWorkspaceConfiguration.TestingModels** will updated. This is working fine. But when i add new elements to the list this will not be shown in the dropdown.

**EDIT2:**
The Task.Run seems to cause the problem. But why? Tasks can not be really the problem because If I call Task.Run for **UpdateConfiguration()** it still works and as well if I make a Task.Run in **PutSetupWorkspaceConfiguration()**

```
    SetupWorkspaceConfiguration = await Task.Run(async () => await setupWorkspaceConfigurationStore.PutSetupWorkspaceConfiguration(projectId)); //does not work
    SetupWorkspaceConfiguration = await setupWorkspaceConfigurationStore.PutSetupWorkspaceConfiguration(projectId); //does work
```

Comment: `the gui does not update` means what exactly? Do you have a new list with different objects in it after the update? Or do you have the same list with the same objects but changed properties on those objects? Your `RaisePropertyChanged` covers only the former case, in the latter case, each of the objects has to `RaisePropertyChanged` for each of its changed properties.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/KMastalerz/44316423d1b582e73ecaf8b563e58e6a

Some quick excample of MVVM, although im not an expert i think this may help.

Comment: @Haukinger: The list is the same but the properties in the list are changing (which is working fine) but new elements which gets added to the list will not shown in the dropdown.

Comment: @KrzysiekMastalerz: Thanks for the link. Do you have more examples because this covers only if you a view and a view-model. There everything works fine for me as well. But when an element to the TestingModels list gets added in my model the gui does not update the dropdown even so the getter is called.

Comment: https://github.com/KMastalerz/TestMVVM

1st you have to update on correct thread. 
2nd this thread has to be free to update UI.

Comment: @KrzysiekMastalerz: You are right it has something to do with threads (see EDIT2) But I thought that RaisePropertyChanged will invoke the UI Thread. Is that not the case?

Comment: @KrzysiekMastalerz when _modifying_ a collection, one has to be on the right thread, when updating a regular property (including _replacing_ a collection), the change notification gets marshalled automatically.

Comment: I think, you don`t need an RaisPropertyChanged. What is missing is a CollectionChanged  event. Possibly this question (or better the answer) can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449196/